# Unhandled JS Exception: Error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i got into this error while trying to run react-native app fresh from init.

heres what i did:

`react-native init NameOfApp`

`react-native run-ios`

and got this screen

[image]

Please help. Im new in react-native.

Btw. My react native version is 0.43.3.

Comment: IIRC you need to `cd` into your project folder before running the app. Have you tried this?

Comment: @YSK yes. I'm already inside my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have everything required?

You will need Node.js, Watchman, the React Native command line interface, and Xcode.

```
brew install node
brew install watchman
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Then create a project with:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-ios
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay already. I didn't notice i was running `npm start` from another project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and got it fixed by running the following code from the current project folde:

```
./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh start --resetCache
```